# How to award tokens to users staking NFTs?

Tags: anchor, transactions, nft, mint, staking

How would you create a token without any value and then mint them to the user who staked the NFT when they want to unstake? Do they pay the transaction fee and how much would it cost to mint a single token? (non-custodial staking)

Answer (score 1):

The tokens that projects use for staking is a simple SPL Token that you can create in code or via a CLI and that you can find here: https://spl.solana.com/token

As for value, the token has none until it is attached to a pool. Regarding mint fees, you indicate in your smart contract who pays. You can take it at your expense from the cash flow of your project, or let the user pay